# Android SDK Full Javdocs with Maven in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, javadoc

I have an Android Maven project using maven-eclipse-plugin and android-maven-plugin. Since it grabs the jars and javadocs from Maven Central (which are stubbed), I would like to instead link back to the javadocs in the Android SDK folder.

I have tried two things

1. Packaging the $ANDROID_HOME/docs/reference folder into a Jar, and then manually installing that as the Javadocs for Android 2.2.1 in Maven using `mvn install:install-file`.
2. Manually defining the javadoc location of the android-2.2.1.jar on my build path as $ANDROID_HOME/docs/reference

Neither of these have had any success in actually linking back the correct Javadocs - I remain with the stubbed ones that don't give any actually information about the methods. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a missing feature for the m2e-android plugin (http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/). You might want to raise an enhancement request against that project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work in your IDE setup.

However Eclipse might be confused since the source and the binary artifact will not correspond to each other again because the original android jar in the SDK as well as in the Central Repository are both stubbed.

That said I have never tried to hook this up together either and I am using IntelliJ so I would not be able to help you with Eclipse much..