# How to use code automation for Android Projects?

Tags: android, maven, build-automation

I am extremely new to the idea of Build Automation, and am not sure if it would be helpful for me or not. Honestly, I'm not exactly sure what it does or the benefits of it. I've been looking up a lot of information about Maven, and am having a bit of trouble piecing it all together.

Right now I develop a lot of similar Android applications. Most of these applications have a similar base of functionality which I copy from one application to the next. However, when I make changes to one part of that "main functionality," I need to go back and apply the changes to other applications. This is horribly inefficient, obviously. What I've been beginning to do is to set the main functionality as a library which is then imported by each application. So far so good.

So in addition to the library approach I'm using, would Maven be helpful? Is there something else more helpful that I haven't seen yet? Sorry for the really basic questions and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven will not help you for code generation it will only help you to automate your build process.

You can configure your eclipse using maven plugin for android [Android SDK Full Javdocs with Maven in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522707/android-sdk-full-javdocs-with-maven-in-eclipse)

I have not used Maven for android project as of now since currently I am using Ant for that purpose. You will find sample maven and ant files in the examples in android SDK

About code Generation:

I have read that [Acceleo](http://www.acceleo.org/pages/home/en) provides support for android based UML Code generations.